# How to passing a nil value in a in parameter of procedure of object type

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, delphi-xe

I want to pass a nil value in a parameter which is declarated as `procedure of object`

Consider this code

### Case 1

```
type
  TFooProc = procedure(Foo1, Foo2 : Integer) of object;


procedure DoSomething(Param1:Integer;Foo:TFooProc);overload;
var
  a, b : Integer;
begin
   a:=b*Param1;
   //If foo is assigned
   if @Foo<>nil then
    Foo(a, b);
end;

procedure DoSomething(Param1:Integer);overload;
begin      
  DoSomething(Param1,nil);//here the delphi compiler raise this message [DCC Error] E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'DoSomething' that can be called with these arguments
end;
```

### Case 2

Ì found, if I declare `TFooProc` as `procedure` type the code is compiled. (but in my case I need a `procedure of object` type)

```
type
  TFooProc = procedure(Foo1, Foo2 : Integer);


procedure DoSomething(Param1:Integer;Foo:TFooProc);overload;
var
  a, b : Integer;
begin
   a:=b*Param1;
   //If foo is assigned
   if @Foo<>nil then
    Foo(a, b);
end;

procedure DoSomething(Param1:Integer);overload;
begin
  DoSomething(Param1,nil);
end;
```

### Case 3

Also I discover which if remove the `overload` directive the code compiles fine

```
type
  TFooProc = procedure(Foo1, Foo2 : Integer) of object;


procedure DoSomething(Param1:Integer;Foo:TFooProc);
var
  a, b : Integer;
begin
   a:=b*Param1;
   //If foo is assigned
   if @Foo<>nil then
    Foo(a, b);
end;

procedure DoSomething2(Param1:Integer);
begin
  DoSomething(Param1,nil);
end;
```

The question is `How i can pass the nil value as parameter?` to work with the code in the case 1?

Comment: Why are you checking `@foo <> nil`? A simple `Assigned(Foo)` avoids the negation and `Assigned` is generally advised for checking pointers and method references.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typecast the nil to a TFooProc:

```
DoSomething(Param1, TFooProc(nil));
```

Comment: Thanks @Sertac by the workaround, do you know the cause of this delphi compiler behavior?

Comment: @Salvador - Not exactly, it would seem when there's an overload the compiler looks for a more strict match, i.e. the 'nil' seems to be a more natural match for a 'pointer' (a pchar, a type etc..).

Comment: In any case this sure looks like a glitch in the compiler.